# Quotient and remainder in MATLAB

Tags: matlab

I am using [`quorem`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/symbolic/quorem.html) to divide integers and obtain the remainder as well. Is there a MATLAB function that does this quicker?

This operation is actually very time intensive and requires `sym` inputs and outputs `sym` instead of numeric values. Hence, I have to convert the input and the output to resume operations.

Is there a faster way to achieve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do it manually:

```
remainder = mod(nominator, denominator);
quotient = floor(nominator./denominator);
```

I have no clue whether this is faster, but at least you can fill in numerics (or whole arrays) for convenience.

Comment: Actually, it's about 10x faster. I'm surprised no one has made a function in matlab that just uses these functions to return the remainder and quotient at the same time.

Comment: Surprising that it's that much faster - usually the base matlab functions are very efficient. But i guess it's too few lines of code that anybody bothered to share it ;)

Comment: I think perhaps it had to do with the sym conversions also.